# Debugging Remote C Applications

Tags: c, linux, netcat

I'm using the [`GNU Debugger`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) on Linux to debug C programs locally, but how do I do it on remote applications?

Locally, a program can be ran with

```
./programName
```

Gdb can be attached (without welcome text) by writing

```
gdb -q programName
```

To connect to the remote application I have to sign in to the "main" server then switch to another one:

```
netcat serverName portNumber
```

and it will automatically execute the remote application. Gdb is available on that machine. I tried `gdb netcat serverName portNumber` but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you read the GDB manual at https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html#Remote-Debugging ?

Comment: if gdb is available on the remote server, logon to that remote server and run gdb on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch gdbserver on the remote target like this:

On Target Machine,

```
$ gdbserver ip_address_host:port programName
```

On Host Machine,

```
$ gdb programName
(gdb) target remote ip_address_server:port
```

Comment: Yeah but that won't work if I don't control the target machine so in case I don't it's impossible.